# Is it a recommended practice to scale down the AKS usernodepools to 0 dring non work hours?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

We are using AKS 1.19.1 in our sandbox environment and have both system and user nodepools seperately. We have multiple applications running in our user nodepools along with istio as service mesh. Current node count of the usernodepool is 24 and auto scaling is enabled.

Now as part of cost optimisation, we are planning to scale down the usernodepool to zero during the non working hours ( say after office time or during night time).

```
Reference:-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/scale-cluster
```

Will this be recommended way to do scale down to zero nodes for such a cluster with nodepool size of 25 nodes

if yes,

When we renable autoscaling property (everyday after making the count to zero at night) , will this automatically increase node count and application pods will be auto sterted or, we need to rollout the restart of the pods seperately?

What are the factors it depends to back the normal running state and how long it may take?

Is there any way to schedule this feature of scaling down to zero during night and then again renable autoscaling property at morning automatically

Comment: Interesting idea, but won't your pods move to the system nodepool if you scale down the user pool without also scaling down the number of pods? That can be handled by taints, I guess. We scale down the pods instead and allow the nodes to auto-scale down when not used (but never below one node).

Comment: but how will scale down automatically in this scenario on the basis of time not the basis of minimum resource requests ( like night time the pods should scale down and morining it should scale up), which should do to entire cluster?

Comment: I assumed you were going to scale down the usernodepool with a scheduled script (running in AKS as a cronjob or outside)? The same can be done to change maxpods for the hpa policies or (if not using hpa) the number of replicas.

Answer (score -1):

Just use KEDA and let it manage the scale up / down for you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/aks-app-scale-keda/